# Formula for lmer()

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

**How does the formula for the `lmer` function work?**

Some examples:

```
library('lmer')
lmer(Yield~(1|Batch),Dyestuff)
lmer(Yield~(Batch)*(1|rep(c(1,2,3),10)),Dyestuff)
lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject) + (0+Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
```

On the left of `~` sign is the dependent variable and on the right comes all the independent variables separated by the `+` sign.

Is there any difference between `+` and `*`?

What does `1|Batch` mean? Does it have to do with the intercept? With being a random or a fixed effect?

What does `Day|Subjects` mean?

Comment: `(1|Batch)` means "one intercept per batch".

Comment: `(Days|Subject)` means a random intercept *and* a random slope for each subject. `(1|Subject)` would mean only a random intercept but a common slope across subjects.